# Why does the code return wrong multiplication?

Tags: python

my study question is:
 Define a procedure, total_enrollment,
 that takes as an input a list of elements,
 where each element is a list containing
 three elements: a university name,
 the total number of students enrolled,
 and the annual tuition fees.

The procedure should return two numbers,
 not a string, 
 giving the total number of students
 enrolled at all of the universities
 in the list, and the total tuition fees
 (which is the sum of the number
 of students enrolled times the
 tuition fees for each university).

the code given is:

```
usa_univs = [ ['California Institute of Technology',2175,37704],
          ['Harvard',19627,39849],
          ['Massachusetts Institute of Technology',10566,40732],
          ['Princeton',7802,37000],
          ['Rice',5879,35551],
          ['Stanford',19535,40569],
          ['Yale',11701,40500]  ]
```

my solution is:

```
def total_enrollment(a):
    total_students = 0
    costsum = 0
    for e in a:
        total_students = total_students + e[1]
        costsum = costsum + e[2]
    all_in_all = total_students * costsum
    return total_students
    return all_in_all
```

what I should see is:
77285,3058581079

What actually comes out is:
77285 - and no total number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can't return twice, change your code to this in order to return a tuple.

Also I fixed your math for calculating total cost.  You were multiplying total students by total cost, you want to calculate each university separately.  Students at CalTech are going to pay $37704, not the total cost of all universities.

```
def total_enrollment(a):
    total_students = 0
    all_in_all = 0
    for e in a:
        total_students = total_students + e[1]
        all_in_all += (e[1] * e[2])
    return (total_students, all_in_all)
```

Then you could access them like this

```
>>>result = total_enrollment(usa_univs)
>>>print result[0]
77285
>>>print result[1]
3058581079
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've made that change but the second answer still comes out wrong as 21014177925 instead of 3058581079. Any idea why that is the case?

Comment: Why would it matter that I am calculating it outside the loop? from my basic understanding the loop would finish through all the cycles giving the correct number to total_students and the correct number to costsum. Since python evaluates all_in_all after the for loops has gone through all the times shouldn't it give the correct number? Just trying to understand why it wouldn't work so I don't do the same mistake again in the future.

Comment: Because you are making all the students each pay the total amount for everybody, I assume you want the total amount of money spent on college.  To do that you calculate total spent for each university separately @user2093601

Comment: that makes perfect sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

You can't return twice from a function. You can rather return both the values as `tuple`:

```
return total_students, all_in_all
```

And then unpack the return value in two variables.

*E.g.:*

```
>>> def func():
...     return 1, 2
... 
>>> v1, v2 = func()
>>> v1
1
>>> v2
2
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've made that change but the second answer still comes out wrong as 21014177925 instead of 3058581079. Any idea why that is the case?

Comment: A1*B1 + A2*B2 != (A1+A2) * (B1+B2).  Your math is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

"Thanks for the clarification. I've made that change but the second answer still comes out wrong as 21014177925 instead of 3058581079. Any idea why that is the case?"

The error is here:

```
for e in a:
    total_students = total_students + e[1]
    costsum = costsum + e[2]
```

You are summing up the costs for every university and then multiplying this sum -- which is greater than the cost of an individual's education -- by every student.  Think about whether or not this is what you really want to do.

Comment: It may be helpful for you to mentally or on paper step through this loop to see why it is not the right logic.

Comment: that is the point he is trying to make, the code he posted is the error not the solution

Comment: huh?  I don't quite understand.